# Unresponsive TableView while WebRequest (AFNetworking) on device, but ok in simulator + MagicalRecord issue

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an application that retrieves json (employees workschedules) from a web service using AFNetworking and displays them in a table view.

I have my webservice class that takes care of doing the request and once it is done, it stores these data into coredata (I have an another issue here, being that I use magicalRecord and the data does not persist, and I don't understand why) and then calls back its delegate (my tableViewController) telling it it's done, so this can load the workschedules into the cells.

WebServiceClient.m

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
    {
        NSArray *workSchedules = [[[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:JSON] allObjects];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
        Workschedule *workscheduleEntity = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        for (NSDictionary *web_workschedule in workSchedules) 
        {//Inside this method I create other entities that will hydrate my workschedule entity, and it is done using the MR_CreateInContext
          workscheduleEntity = [Workschedule workScheduleFromJSONDictionary:web_workschedule  withError:&error];
          [context MR_save];
        }
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(workSchedules)]){
           [self.delegate workSchedules];
        }
    } 
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        LOG_ERROR(2,@"Received an HTTTP %d:", response.statusCode);
        LOG_ERROR(2,@"The error was: %@", error);
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(workSchedules:)]){
        [self.delegate workSchedules:nil];//return error
    }}];
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation]; 
}
```

PendingWorkscheduleViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webServiceClient getMockedWorkSchedulesForEmployee:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    [self workSchedules];
}

-(void)workSchedules
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pending == YES"];
    NSArray *pendingWorkSchedules = [Workschedule MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
    self.pendingWorkSchedules = pendingWorkSchedules;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

My problem is that when i run this while the request is processed the UI is unresponsive (it's a very brief time, but if the request were to increase...) so that if i load the table view and right away try to scroll or click the back button, it just ignores it as it is "frozen". This behavior is on my iphone 4s. On the simulator this **works** fine and I can't wrap my head around why is that. I tried to call the "[self.webServiceClient getMockedWorkSchedulesForEmployee:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];" in a queue using GCD, I tried using performSelectorInBackground: WithObject: etc but still the same (even though with this last method it seemed a little more efficient, but it's an impression and only on the simulator, no changes on the device).

As far as magicalRecord goes I will make separate question.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem is that the success block run on the main thread! (which I did not understand). I just used GCD in the success block with a background queue for processing the data and the main queue to store this data in core data.

As far as magical record issue, i needed to save "nestedContext".

Cheers everyone.

Comment: That explains why it was OK in the simulator: your computer is much faster than your iOS device!

Comment: yeah, I added some extra useless code to make it "wait" longer and verify that it was going to do the same in the simulator. (Before I found the problem).

Comment: Hi, I am running in the same issue, could you share how did you solved this issue? I appreciate, thanx in a advance.